# How do I show the value of a #define at compile-time?

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

I am trying to figure out what version of Boost my code thinks it's using. I want to do something like this:

`#error BOOST_VERSION`

but the preprocessor does not expand BOOST_VERSION.

I know I could print it out at run-time from the program, and I know I could look at the output of the preprocessor to find the answer. I feel like having a way of doing this during compilation could be useful.

Comment: Adjacently related: [How can I print the result of `sizeof()` at compile time in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20979565/4561887)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

I know that this is a long time after the original query, but this may still be useful.

This can be done in GCC using the stringify operator "#", but it requires two additional stages to be defined first.

```
#define XSTR(x) STR(x)
#define STR(x) #x
```

The value of a macro can then be displayed with:

```
#pragma message "The value of ABC: " XSTR(ABC)
```

See: 3.4 Stringification in the gcc online documentation.

How it works:

The preprocessor understands quoted strings and handles them differently from normal text. String concatenation is an example of this special treatment. The message pragma requires an argument that is a quoted string. When there is more than one component to the argument then they must all be strings so that string concatenation can be applied. The preprocessor can never assume that an unquoted string should be treated as if it were quoted. If it did then:

```
#define ABC 123
int n = ABC;
```

would not compile.

Now consider:

```
#define ABC abc
#pragma message "The value of ABC is: " ABC
```

which is equivalent to

```
#pragma message "The value of ABC is: " abc
```

This causes a preprocessor warning because abc (unquoted) cannot be concatenated with the preceding string.

Now consider the preprocessor stringize (Which was once called stringification, the links in the documentation have been changed to reflect the revised terminology. (Both terms, incidentally, are equally detestable. The correct term is, of course, stringifaction. Be ready to update your links.)) operator. This acts only on the arguments of a macro and replaces the unexpanded argument with the argument enclosed in double quotes. Thus:

```
#define STR(x) #x
char *s1 = "abc";
char *s2 = STR(abc);
```

will assign identical values to s1 and s2. If you run gcc -E you can see this in the output. Perhaps STR would be better named something like ENQUOTE.

This solves the problem of putting quotes around an unquoted item, the problem now is that, if the argument is a macro, the macro will not be expanded. This is why the second macro is needed. XSTR expands its argument, then calls STR to put the expanded value into quotes.

Comment: I'm curious as to why it requires two stages

Comment: @VincentFourmond Without the XSTR stage, the macro isn't expanded. So if you did #define ABC 42 \n STR(ABC) you'd get "ABC". See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

Comment: This also works great with Xcode 8, e.g. replacing ABC with `__IPHONE_9_3`.

Comment: GCC terminology seems to have changed, and with it the URL, which is now [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringizing.html#Stringizing)

Comment: Didn't work for me, the message that I see is "The value of ABC: XSTR(ABC)"

Comment: @Maxim: You cannot put the XSTR(ABC) inside the quotes. It has to be outside of the quotes.

Comment: It doesn't work for me on gcc 9 with

#pragma message "TEST " XSTR(PF_RING_VERSION)

Comment: What threw me initially is that #pragma message line got printed out verbatim (as in the source code), however, looking a line above this you will see `note:` prefixed to the evaluated string.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the `note: in expansion of macro 'XSTR'` / `in definition of macro 'STR'` lines?

Comment: I was having trouble getting this to work with gcc 9.3 when the macro was defined as `#define METHODDEF static type`. What did work was to add `#define METHODDEF` causing a 'redefined' error that showed the actual expansion and where it was set, which was kinda nice.

Comment: It doesn't do the math for me, just prints out the whole expression: `The value of ABC: (((16/8 * 96 * 2 / 2*8)/4) + 16/8 * 2)` Is there a way to print `The value of ABC: 388`?

Comment: Note that as of 2023 you'll have to add round brackets around the message part, as in `#pragma message(...)`, otherwise you'll only get a build warning but no message.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the macro is an integer, like `1`. Ex: `#define UART_ENABLE 1`. How can I print the value of `UART_ENABLE` to see that it is `1`?

Comment: Nevermind. It works fine. I was looking on the wrong line. I was focusing on the red lines in my particular output, which had the `#pragma message` line from the code, when I should have been looking at the _blue_ lines in my output, which had the _processed_ output of that pragma message!

Answer (score 136):

`BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE` seems a excellent solution for C++, but not for regular C.

Here is my solution for GNU CPP:

```
/* Some test definition here */
#define DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE
#define DEFINED_INT 3
#define DEFINED_STR "ABC"

/* definition to expand macro then apply to pragma message */
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#define VAR_NAME_VALUE(var) #var "="  VALUE(var)

/* Some example here */
#pragma message(VAR_NAME_VALUE(NOT_DEFINED))
#pragma message(VAR_NAME_VALUE(DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE))
#pragma message(VAR_NAME_VALUE(DEFINED_INT))
#pragma message(VAR_NAME_VALUE(DEFINED_STR))
```

Above definitions result in:

```
test.c:10:9: note: #pragma message: NOT_DEFINED=NOT_DEFINED
test.c:11:9: note: #pragma message: DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE=
test.c:12:9: note: #pragma message: DEFINED_INT=3
test.c:13:9: note: #pragma message: DEFINED_STR="ABC"
```

For **"defined as interger"**, **"defined as string"**, and **"defined but no value"** variables , they work just fine. Only for **"not defined"** variable, they displayed exactly the same as original variable name. You have to used to it -- or maybe someone can provide a better solution.

Comment: excellent! Any experiences in ARM RVCT? it seems has no "Stringification" feature as GCC http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491c/CIHHDEAA.html

Comment: Great solution. However, if I wish to display the size of a compile-time calculated value, e.g. the size of a complex struct, can this be done? The method suggested in this answer seems to generate `DEFINED_INT=(sizeof(MY_STRUCT))`, without the `sizeof` operator being evaluated.

Comment: (Comment addition: not unexpected, since it is the compiler rather than the pre-processor that will evaluate `sizeof`, however, still curious if there's a clever way of achieving this.)

Comment: @xdan Good solution, unfortunately is doesn't cater for things like `#define masks {0xff, 0xaf, 0x0f}`

Comment: @Carl, here's how to do that: [How can I print the result of `sizeof()` at compile time in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35261673/4561887). The size of the struct gets put into a crazy compile-time error message, but it works.

Comment: @SimonBagley, it worked fine with code blocks in my tests, so long as you don't do function-like macros with a `()` after the name, as in: `#define MY_MACRO() { /* stuff here */ }`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77695006/4561887).

Answer (score 61):

If you are using Visual C++, you can use `#pragma message`:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp>
#pragma message("BOOST_VERSION=" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_VERSION))
```

**Edit:** Thanks to LB for link

Apparently, the GCC equivalent is (not tested):

```
#pragma message "BOOST_VERSION=" BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(BOOST_VERSION)
```

Comment: That's called diagnostic pragmas, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas

Comment: Would be nice if you included [the definition of `BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/preprocessor/stringize.hpp) which is nice and short and copy/pasteable.

Comment: Works fine under gcc :)

Answer (score 15):

As far as I know '#error' only will print strings, in fact [you don't even need to use quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#User-defined_compilation_errors_and_warnings).

Have you tried writing various purposefully incorrect code using "BOOST_VERSION"?  Perhaps something like "blah[BOOST_VERSION] = foo;" will tell you something like "string literal 1.2.1 cannot be used as an array address".  It won't be a pretty error message, but at least it'll show you the relevant value.  You can play around until you find a compile error that does tell you the value.

Comment: That didn't work, since BOOST_VERSION is an integer, but I got to see it with this statement: `std::vector<BOOST_VERSION>;` in gcc 4.4.1.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that with Visual C++, you would have to use Bojan Resnik's answer.

Comment: I tried to get this to work, but the error message GCC gave me were sadly undescriptive. But +1 for mentioning it.

Answer (score 15):

Without boost :

1. define same macro again and compiler HIMSELF will give warning.
2. From warning you can see location of the previous definition.
3. vi file of previous definition .

```
ambarish@axiom:~/cpp$ g++ shiftOper.cpp
shiftOper.cpp:7:1: warning: "LINUX_VERSION_CODE" redefined
shiftOper.cpp:6:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition

#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 265216
#define LINUX_VERSION_CODE 666

int main ()
{

}
```

Comment: This one is easier and straightforward.

Comment: _itself_ : compilers have no gender

Comment: This does not work with predefined macros, such as ```__cplusplus```.

Answer (score 13):

In Microsoft C/C++, you can use the built-in `_CRT_STRINGIZE()` to print constants. Many of my `stdafx.h` files contain some combination of these:

```
#pragma message("_MSC_VER      is " _CRT_STRINGIZE(_MSC_VER))
#pragma message("_MFC_VER      is " _CRT_STRINGIZE(_MFC_VER))
#pragma message("_ATL_VER      is " _CRT_STRINGIZE(_ATL_VER))
#pragma message("WINVER        is " _CRT_STRINGIZE(WINVER))
#pragma message("_WIN32_WINNT  is " _CRT_STRINGIZE(_WIN32_WINNT))
#pragma message("_WIN32_IE     is " _CRT_STRINGIZE(_WIN32_IE))
#pragma message("NTDDI_VERSION is " _CRT_STRINGIZE(NTDDI_VERSION))
```

and outputs something like this:

```
_MSC_VER      is 1915
_MFC_VER      is 0x0E00
_ATL_VER      is 0x0E00
WINVER        is 0x0600
_WIN32_WINNT  is 0x0600
_WIN32_IE     is 0x0700
NTDDI_VERSION is 0x06000000
```

Answer (score 6):

```
#define a <::BOOST_VERSION>
#include a
```

> **MSVC2015**: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '::106200': No such file or directory

*Pros*:

- Works on builtin macroses
- Works even if `preprocess to file` is enabled, even if invalid tokens are present:

```
#define a <::'*/`#>
#include a
```

> **MSVC2015**: fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '::'*/`#': No such file or directory
> **GCC4.x**: warning: missing terminating ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]
>     #define a <::'*/`#>

*Cons*:

- Sometime fails because of invalid characters in the include file path. Can be fixed by change a prefix (see update section below).

**Update**:

For GCC 4.7.x and lower the output throws the error:

> error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>

To fix that you can change the prefix:

```
#define a <.__cplusplus>
#include a
```

```
fatal error: .201103L: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Mine just says `Build error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>`.  Sigh.

Comment: @endolith what compiler and version?

Comment: DP8051 Keil 9.51 :)

Comment: @endolith Seems this compiler is very limited on preprocessing: http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_pp_directives.htm But, on mine side it almost works as expected, i've just removed some of invalid characters like `'`: `*** WARNING C318 IN LINE 2 OF test.c: can't open file '::*/\`'`

Comment: Thank you, this saved me because the pragma message stuff wasn't implemented in the compiler I was using.

Answer (score 3):

You could also preprocess the source file and see what the preprocessor value evaluates to.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the output of the preprocessor is the closest thing to the answer you ask for.

I know you've excluded that (and other ways), but I'm not sure why. You have a specific enough problem to solve, but you have not explained why any of the "normal" methods don't work well for you.

Comment: This is probably the correct answer to the general problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a program that prints out `BOOST_VERSION` and compile and run it as part of your build system. Otherwise, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: For the case of a software version defined in a header you're probably safe (and it's a good answer).  But as a general solution, a possible downside would be in getting your test app and your real app to have the same value of the #define - depending on their include paths, other #defines that may be used to set the value of that one, the CFLAGS passed to the compiler, etc.

Comment: Print it out from your real program.  If graphical, put it in the "about" dialog.   If command-line, make it an option (part of --version, maybe).  If a daemon, write it to a log file.  If embedded, find some other way.

Comment: @swillden - The OP wanted it at compile time, not at runtime.

Comment: This also tends to break cross-compiler based builds

Comment: This is what I'm ending up doing, even though I'm cross-compiling for the AVR CPUs from LINUX. All the preprocessor calculations are in the header file, it it's easy enough to write a short program to test the values. I might use the accepted solution as well but both are better than trying to read an object dump file.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for

```
#if BOOST_VERSION != "1.2"
#error "Bad version"
#endif
```

Not great if BOOST_VERSION is a string, like I've assumed, but there may also be individual integers defined for the major, minor and revision numbers.

Comment: I think the submitter doesn't want to (just) enforce a particular value, they want to see what the current value is.

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me.  I can change the `#if VARIABLE == 123` statement on the fly and the syntax highlighting tells me whether it's the value I think it is or not...

Answer (score 1):

BOOST_VERSION is defined in the boost header file version.hpp.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Boost documentation as well, regarding how you are using the macro:

In reference to `BOOST_VERSION`, from http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.boost_helper_macros:

> Describes the boost version number in
>   XXYYZZ format such that:
>   **`(BOOST_VERSION % 100)`** is the sub-minor
>   version, **`((BOOST_VERSION / 100) %`**
>   **`1000)`** is the minor version, and
>   **`(BOOST_VERSION / 100000)`** is the major
>   version.

Answer (score 1):

##### Print expanded macro values at compile-time

This is an extension of [@Jackie Yeh's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10227059/4561887).

The magic helper macros, with my minor tweaks:

```c
// Helper macros to print the value of a macro at compile-time
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"
```

To use them:

```c
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_INT)
```

A **word of caution:** if the macro is *not defined*, its name will just be printed out again! So, if your macro is called `MY_MACRO`, but you never define it, then doing this:

```c
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_MACRO)
```

...will print out something like this:

```c
../main.c:1000:63: note: #pragma message: MY_MACRO=`MY_MACRO`
```

**So, look for `` MY_MACRO=`MY_MACRO` ``  type output when compiling as a clear sign that `MY_MACRO` is not defined!**

This threw me off for a while and I lost a lot of time not realizing this.

---

I want to show that this works with code blocks too. So, here's my full example:

[`macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c) from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/tree/master) repo:

```c
///usr/bin/env ccache gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu17 "$0" -o /tmp/a -lm && /tmp/a "$@"; exit
// For the line just above, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491834/4561887

#include <stdbool.h> // For `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) macros in C
#include <stdint.h>  // For `uint8_t`, `int8_t`, etc.
#include <stdio.h>   // For `printf()`

// Various macro definitions to test
#define DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE
#define MY_INT 3
#define MY_STR "ABC"
#define MY_CODE_BLOCK           \
    do                          \
    {                           \
        printf("Hi 1.\n");      \
    } while (0)
//
// NB: the `#pragma message` output of the above macro is substantially different if I define it as
// `MY_CODE_BLOCK()` instead, and call it as such inside `main()`! Try it out and you'll see.
//
#define MY_CODE_BLOCK2          \
    {                           \
        printf("Hi 2.\n");      \
    }

// Helper macros to print the value of a macro at compile-time
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"

// Example prints at compile-time
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(NOT_DEFINED)
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE)
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_INT)
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_STR)
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_CODE_BLOCK)
#pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_CODE_BLOCK2)


// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    MY_CODE_BLOCK;
    MY_CODE_BLOCK2;
    printf("Hello World.\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Build and run commands, and output, in both C and C++:

In C:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ ./macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c
./macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:74:9: note: ‘#pragma message: NOT_DEFINED=`NOT_DEFINED`’
   74 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(NOT_DEFINED)
      |         ^~~~~~~
./macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:75:9: note: ‘#pragma message: DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE=``’
   75 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE)
      |         ^~~~~~~
./macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:76:9: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_INT=`3`’
   76 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_INT)
      |         ^~~~~~~
./macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:77:9: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_STR=`"ABC"`’
   77 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_STR)
      |         ^~~~~~~
./macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:78:9: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_CODE_BLOCK=`do { printf("Hi 1.\n"); } while (0)`’
   78 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_CODE_BLOCK)
      |         ^~~~~~~
./macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:79:9: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_CODE_BLOCK2=`{ printf("Hi 2.\n"); }`’
   79 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_CODE_BLOCK2)
      |         ^~~~~~~
Hi 1.
Hi 2.
Hello World.
```

Or, in C++:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=gnu++17 macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c -o bin/a && bin/a
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:71:63: note: ‘#pragma message: NOT_DEFINED=`NOT_DEFINED`’
   71 | #define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"
      |                                                               ^~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:74:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME’
   74 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(NOT_DEFINED)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:71:63: note: ‘#pragma message: DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE=``’
   71 | #define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"
      |                                                               ^~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:75:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME’
   75 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(DEFINED_BUT_NO_VALUE)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:71:63: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_INT=`3`’
   71 | #define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"
      |                                                               ^~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:76:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME’
   76 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_INT)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:71:63: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_STR=`"ABC"`’
   71 | #define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"
      |                                                               ^~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:77:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME’
   77 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_STR)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:71:63: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_CODE_BLOCK=`do { printf("Hi 1.\n"); } while (0)`’
   71 | #define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"
      |                                                               ^~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:78:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME’
   78 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_CODE_BLOCK)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:71:63: note: ‘#pragma message: MY_CODE_BLOCK2=`{ printf("Hi 2.\n"); }`’
   71 | #define PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(var) #var "=`" VALUE(var) "`"
      |                                                               ^~~
macro_print_macro_values_at_compile_time.c:79:17: note: in expansion of macro ‘PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME’
   79 | #pragma message PRINT_MACRO_AT_COMPILE_TIME(MY_CODE_BLOCK2)
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Hi 1.
Hi 2.
Hello World.
```

### Adjacently-related

1. My answer on [Printing the size of (`sizeof()`) a type or variable in an error message at compile time in both C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78144837/4561887)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of #error, try redefining the macro, just before it is being used. Compilation will fail and compiler will provide the current value it thinks applies to the macro.

#define BOOST_VERSION blah