# C preprocessor: what is the motivation behind not macro-expanding arguments of #error directive?

Tags: c, macros, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

What is the motivation / rationale behind not macro-expanding arguments of `#error` (and `#warning`) directive?

The [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Diagnostics.html) explicitly states:

> Neither ‘#error’ nor ‘#warning’ macro-expands its argument.

P.S. For `#warning` (not standardized) the fix is to use `#pragma message` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/12638158/1778275), which (normally) macro-expands its arguments.

UPD. The question is not specifically about *why gcc does not perform macro-expantion*. The quote from `gcc` documentation is used as an example of text, which explicitly states that `neither #error nor #warning macro-expands its argument`. I could not find this (or similar) text in C standard. Hence, refer the quite from `gcc` documentation.

UPD2. In comparison with `#error` the `#include` performs macro-expantion of its arguments. Quote from the standard (ISO/IEC 9899:202x (E)):

> The preprocessing tokens after **include** in the directive are processed just as in normal text. (Each identifier currently defined as a macro name is replaced by its replacement list of preprocessing tokens.)

Comment: Since that is GCC documentation, the motivation for `#error` is of course that it is conforming to the C standard, which specifies this in C 2018 6.10.5. Presumably you then want to know why the C standard does not specify any expansion for those tokens.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's much of a rationale behind any of it. A lot of stuff originating from back in C89 was just added to the language at a whim. Like, who could have guessed that when writing something like `#if FOO != BAR #error FOO is not BAR`, I might be also be interested in knowing the values of FOO and BAR...

Comment: The C standard does not preclude the error message not have the contents expanded **as well**, it just requires that a message without the contents expanded is produced.

Comment: As for `#warning`, the rationale supposedly is that if you change `#error` to `#warning` its behaviour wouldn't change other than it outputting a message with slightly different format and not terminating compilation. `#warning` is *not* in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

I don't say this is the motivation for the standard, but thinking of many of my uses of `#error` it would be inconvenient to have it macro-expanded.
Admittedly, my habits might have been formed by the non-expansion.

```
#define MINIMUMCONFIG 1
#ifndef IMPORTANTCONFIG
#error  IMPORTANTCONFIG is undefined!
#error
#if     IMPORTANTCONFIG < MINIMUMCONFIG
#error  IMPORTANTCONFIG lower than MINIMUMCONFIG !
#endif
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the example.