# Is it possible to show the value of a #define at compile-time with ARM RVCT?

Tags: c++, c, arm

Question has been answered with VC and GCC in
[How do I show the value of a #define at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562074/how-do-i-show-the-value-of-a-define-at-compile-time)
but is it possible to do it with ARM RVCT?
Actually I can do my own macro2string convertion as RVCT doesn't have stringification support. But I didn't even find "#pragma message" support in RVCT. It seems it has only something like

```
#pragma diag_error 223
```

which you must specify a tag, you can not freely output a string.

In fact I work on some legacy code now, here is an simplified example from the code base:

in product_conf.h:

```
#define VALUE_A 1
```

in platform_conf.h:

```
#ifndef VALUE_A
#define VALUE_A 2
#endif
```

in component_conf.h:

```
#ifndef VALUE_A
#define VALUE_A 3
#endif
```

in component.c:

```
#include product_conf.h
#include platform_conf.h
#include component_conf.h
```

It is a bit difficult to know VALUE_A is 1 or 2 or 3 when you are reading the component.c, actually in the real cases there can be 4~5 layers configurations and the c files may include or not include some certain conf.h, you have to go through the different header files case by case.
So I thought something like:

```
/* definition to expand macro then apply to pragma message */
#define VALUE_TO_STRING(x) #x
#define VALUE(x) VALUE_TO_STRING(x)
#define VAR_NAME_VALUE(var) #var "="  VALUE(var[[)]]
#pragma message(VAR_NAME_VALUE(VALUE_A))
```

will help for a quick check, I just make the component and I will find out what is defined in the compiling output. This is doable with GCC, but I want to know how to do similar things with ARM RVCT.
or the only way to do it is:

```
#if (VALUE_A==1)
#warning "VALUE_A is 1"
#elif (VALUE_A==2)
#warning "VALUE_A is 2"
#elif (VALUE_A==3)
#warning "VALUE_A is 3"
#else
#error "VALUE_A is not properly defined!"
#endif
```

Comment: Things like `#error` and `#pragma` are very much dependent on the compiler. It's not a standard thing, and so can not be expected to be supported by every compiler.

Comment: Can you give of brief example of how you might want to use it?

Comment: Hi I update the original question with an example

Comment: From [RCVT pre-processor flags](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0282b/Chdeccjc.html), use the `-E` option and *stringify* to convert the define to a string.  Inspect the output.

Comment: You can also use `gcc` to pre-process and `RCVT` to generate code.