# Show how of a typedef declaration has been defined?

Tags: c, typedef

How can I show the compiler's definition of a `typedef` during compilation of a C program?

I know I can show how a macro is defined using e.g. `#pragma message`, see [How do I show the value of a #define at compile-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1562074/2173773), but I could not find a similar procedure for `typedef`s.

Being able to dump a `typedef`s definition during compile time (or run time) could help debugging programs you did not write yourself.

Comment: You can do things with typedef that you can't do (at all easily) with macros — pointers to functions are an example; pointers generally are an issue, but you shouldn't be using typedef on pointers willy-nilly anyway.  `#pragma message` is not standard — the C standard does not define what it does.  There isn't a standard way to find the mappings for typedefs.  Your nearest approach might be to view the output from the C preprocessor (often `-E` or `-P` option to the C compiler, or perhaps run `cpp` as a standalone program), but that's not exactly neat or simple (it is very verbose, usually).

Comment: There is always grepping for the typedef definition.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes `grep` is a quite powerful, and I have used it. But sometimes it seems not enough. For example if the `typedef` is nested in an `#if` - `#elif` clause that depends on other defined symbols. However, in this case, I think using the approach suggested by @JonathanLeffler (in the comment above) and running `gcc -E ... | grep MY_TYPE_NAME` might come to rescue?

Comment: (a) Easy but requires manual work for each case: Pass an object of the type to a function taking some different type and read the compiler error message. (b) Hard, implementation-dependent, but can be automated: Interpret the debug information produced by the compiler. This requires digging up documentation on the data the compiler generates for use by debuggers and writing a lot of code to interpret that data. Alternatively, some scripting to run a debugger and make it print the type might work.